# How can i make equal two references by using RETURN VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, function, reference, return

I have this codes

```
 Public ReceteSN As String()
 Public EldenSN As String()
```

and

```
Private Function degerata(ByVal i As Integer) As String()

        If i = 0 Then Return EldenSN 
        If i = 1 Then Return UrunCikisSN 
End Function
```

and

```
Public Sub Set2()

        Dim x As Short
        Dim y As Short
        For x = 0 To obj.Length - 1
            For y = 0 To obj(x).Length - 1
                degerata(x)= "identify" & x
            Next
        Next

End Sub
```

But i can not return my references by using SUB FUNCTION. how can i make  EldenSN(0) = "indetify0" ?

Comment: `degerata(0)(x) = ...`?

Comment: i want to add some values to the references "EldenSN" and "UruncikisSN" by using "degerata". But i can not do that without writing EldenSN="..." or UruncikisSN="..."

Comment: Yes you can, using the code I just showed you. `degerata(<0 or 1>)(<index>) = "<value>"`.

Comment: No. When i use "Console.WriteLine(EldenSN(0))" returns nothing.

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong. It works fine: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NyRC0S

Comment: i am trying to not use "degerata". Only EldenSN.

Comment: What do you mean? You're trying to use `degerata` in the loop, just like I am with `GetArray`. Then you write the value of `EldenSN(0)` and I write the value of `Array2(13)`. In my code `GetArray = degerata` and `Array1 = ReceteSN` and `Array2 = EldenSN`.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/szUQfe

Comment: Oh, you must initialize the arrays, like I do in my code. `Dim Array1 As String() = New String(16 - 1) {}` creates an array of 16 elements.

Comment: Can you edit my codes on that web site?

Comment: Not without re-sharing it. This creates an array of 20 elements: `Public Ad As String() = New String(20 - 1) {}`. You should read up on how arrays work: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx

Comment: If you need to dynamically add/remove items you should use a [**`List(Of T)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than an array.